# Haxe and NME crash: "error creating pch"

Tags: haxe, nme

When I try to compile to cpp on OSX Lion with Haxe and NME, I get the following backtrace:

```
[...many lines above this one omitted...]
Called from ? line 1
Called from BuildTool.hx line 1265
Called from BuildTool.hx line 554
Called from a C function
Called from BuildTool.hx line 591
Called from BuildTool.hx line 710
Called from BuildTool.hx line 739
Called from BuildTool.hx line 153
Uncaught exception - Error creating pch: 256 - build cancelled
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following command solved the problem for me:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/haxe/lib/nme/3,4,3/ndll/Mac/tls.ndll /usr/lib/neko/tls.ndll
```

Appears to be a bug on Haxe's part, but until it is resolved, this should fix the problem.